# Inner function call with xargs parameters

Tags: command-line, xargs, basename

I am trying to create a file occurent within my `/tmp` directory of each file containing a speicific string.

The problem is that the call to `basename {}` does not seem to work. Neither this, neither `echo basename {}`.

```
grep -R 'mystring' . | cut -d: -f 1 | uniq | xargs -n 1 -I {} touch /tmp/`basename {}`
```

Does anybody know how could I get the basename function executed on the xargs parameter ?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Has it occurred to you that there may be multiple matching files in different places with the same basename?

Comment: @jw013 I am well aware of this fact. But in this exact case this is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
grep -R 'mystring' . | cut -d: -f 1 | uniq| xargs -n 1 -I {} -t -i ksh  -c "touch /tmp/$(basename {})"
```

Comment: Using `sh` instead of `ksh` works as well.

Comment: Wouldn't you need single quotes there?

Comment: both single and double quto will work for this, its better use single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the backticks are expanded too early (i.e. not once for each argument sent to xargs). There might be a better way, but you should be able to get away with an explicit bash loop:

```
grep -R 'mystring' . | cut -d: -f 1 | uniq | while read f; do touch "/tmp/`basename $f`"; done
```